# Determinants of 3D matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is it possible to have determinants of a 3D matrix that is of the order 2x2x2 or 3x3x3? I have tried some ways to figure it out but it is not working.

Comment: why would you be interested in them? what is the context where you are exposed to 3D matrices?

Comment: What do you mean by a "3D" matrix, and what do you mean by "of the order 2x2x2 or 3x3x3"? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213130/478044

Comment: Or https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdeterminant