Is this generalization of determinant for a higher-order tensor a standard object?
The determinant of an $n$ by $n$ matrix $a$ can be defined as
$$ \mathrm{det}(a)= \sum_{\sigma} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) a_{1,\sigma(1)} a_{2,\sigma(2)} \dots a_{n,\sigma(n)}$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $n$ indices and $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ its signature.
In my physics research, I encountered a similar looking object defined for higher-order tensors (I will use order-4 for concreteness).
Let $J_{ijkl}$ be an order-4 totally antisymmetric tensor with $i,j,k,l$ each running from $1$ to $n$, and let $n$ be a multiple of 4. I am trying to study the following quantity:
$$ \sum_{\sigma} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) J_{\sigma(1) \sigma(2) \sigma(3) \sigma(4)} J_{\sigma(5) \sigma(6) \sigma(7) \sigma(8)} \dots J_{\sigma(n-3) \sigma(n-2) \sigma(n-1) \sigma(n)}$$
I would like to know if this kind of object has a name, and if it happens to be calculable in polynomial time like the determinant is (or at least whether it is calculable in less than $n!$ time).
Thanks a lot.

Did you look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213130/determinant-of-a-tensor#2118449 or hyperdeterminants (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdeterminant) ? That seems to be what you are doing here.

Have you checked if this is independent of the basis chosen? If not it's unlikely it's come up in math before. The sum is also over $n!$ factors, so presumably evaluating it takes that many operations in general.

@quarague it is indeed closely related to the hyperdeterminant, thanks!

@GunnarÞórMagnússon It is basis-independent since it can be rewritten as a contraction with the Levi-Civita tensor

See also the coverage of hyperdeterminants here.

This looks more like a pfaffian than a determinant, and indeed [1] calls your definition divided by $\frac{n}{4}!$ a Barvinok hyperpfaffian which in even order, like here, is equal to the other definition up to a scaling factor that depends on order and dimensions. However, according to [2, 4.2 Theorem] when the order is divisible by 4 the hyperpfaffian is not just in $VNP$ but is $VNP$-complete so if there is a polynomial time algorithm then it would imply $VNP=VP$ which is believed to not hold (more info here). Barvinok original paper, Proposition (4.2.2) gives a $O(4^n)$ algorithm which isn't polynomial but better than $O(n!)$. I couldn't find any other algorithm. It might be faster to compute modulo many small primes and reconstitute the result.
[1]: Daniel Redelmeier, Hyperpfaffians in Algebraic Combinatorics, University of Waterloo, 2006. http://hdl.handle.net/10012/1055, https://dspacemainprd01.lib.uwaterloo.ca/server/api/core/bitstreams/3c039c04-c31e-4b34-824f-0bf31cebcfe0/content
[2]: Christian Ikenmeyer, Michael Walter, Hyperpfaffians and Geometric Complexity Theory, https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09389
[3]: Alexander I. Barvinok, New algorithms for k-matroid intersection and matroid
k-parity problems, Mathematical Programming 69 (1995), 449–470. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01585571, https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/47928/10107_2005_Article_BF01585571.pdf?sequence=1

Very useful, thanks!
